# How to resolve the overlapping Ytick labels in probplot, Matlab?

Tags: matlab, matlab-figure

I am trying to plot a log normal distribution using the matlab function, probplot. But while I do, i am getting an overlap in the yticklabels[image].

I would need that much of a font size (40). Is there a way to eliminate overlaps by providing custom yticklabels esp. with the probplot function ? Please note that the yticklabels for probplot is not straightforward.

Please find the test data in the following [link](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1RKEoEjFTRyIRgNQ_Urli8982AEiMuOXU)

The code is as follows :

```
TestData=importdata('TestData.txt');

h1=probplot('lognormal',TestData,'noref');
set(h1(1),'marker','d','color','b','markersize',8,'markerfacecolor','b');
set(gca,'fontsize',40);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It appears that the *labels* on the *y* axis are not directly the *values* on that axis

```
>> get(gca, 'ytick')
ans =
   -3.7190   -1.6449   -1.2816   -0.6745         0    0.6745    1.2816 ...
```

but rather

```
>> normcdf(get(gca, 'ytick'))
ans =
    0.0001    0.0500    0.1000    0.2500    0.5000    0.7500    0.9000 ...
```

(the number `-1.2816` gave it away that [`normcdf`](https://es.mathworks.com/help/stats/normcdf.html) was involved). Therefore, the labels can be obtained from the values using [`norminv`](https://es.mathworks.com/help/stats/norminv.html). For example,

```
>> norminv(.0001)
ans =
   -3.7190
```

Thus, to specify a set of desired values, use this after the plot has been created:

```
desired_values = [.0001 .005 .05 .25 .75 .95 .995 .9999];
set(gca, 'ytick', norminv(desired_values), 'yticklabels', desired_values);
```

#### Example

Let

```
TestData = exp(randn(1,1e5)); % example data
```

**Before** (that is, plot obtained from your code):

[image]

**After** (that is, using my code on the above plot):

[image]